# Insert php array data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that adds database data into a session shopping cart. That code works good, but I do not know how to store those data from the session shopping cart to database.

Below is my code.

```
//get action string
$action = isset($_GET['action'])?$_GET['action']:"";

//Add to cart
if($action=='addcart' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    //Finding the product by code
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE barCode=:barCode";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam('barCode', $_POST['barCode']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $product = $stmt->fetch();

    $currentQty = $_SESSION['products'][$_POST['barCode']]['qty']+$_POST['sasia']; //Incrementing the product qty in cart
    $_SESSION['products'][$_POST['barCode']] =array('qty'=>$currentQty,'product_name'=>$product['product_name'],'product_image'=>$product['product_image'],'product_id'=>$product['product_id']);
    $product='';

    $q = $_SESSION['products'][$_POST['barCode']]->prepare(" INSERT INTO `orders-3` 
                     SET `product_id` = ?, `product_name` = ?, `product_image` = ?");

 foreach($_SESSION['products'][$_POST['barCode']] as $value){
   $q ->execute( array( $value['product_id'], $value['product_name'], $value['product_image']));
 }

    header("Location:shopping-cart.php");
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“I don’t know how”_ isn’t really a question. You need to be more specific as to what your actual issue is. If you don‘t know how inserting data into a MySQL database from PHP works _in general_ - then you should go read up on that on your own first.

Comment: `$_SESSION['products'][$_POST['barCode']]->prepare(...);`? I have no idea what you're expecting that to do. Just in the lines above, you're using that as an array, and now you're trying to call methods on it?

Comment: It is what I have tried for getting data from uper array and add to database, but do not work.

Comment: You should probably also check if you actually get a response from the first query instead of just assuming you do.

Comment: Of course it won't work. You can't call the method `->prepend()` on random variables (in this case, an array). You need to do that on the database connection. You need to keep track of what your variables contains.